# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.twilio.client.impl.useragent?

Tags: android, twilio

I have tried to connect the call through Twilio android Sdk.I can able to make the call but once i make the call my app is suddenly crashing.

I got the following issue.

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call$Stats com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.getStats(int) (tried Java_com_twilio_client_impl_useragent_Call_getStats and Java_com_twilio_client_impl_useragent_Call_getStats__I)
at com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.getStats(Native Method)
at com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.getStats(Call.java:207)
at com.twilio.client.impl.MetricsPublisher$1.doInBackground(MetricsPublisher.java:90)
at com.twilio.client.impl.MetricsPublisher$1.doInBackground(MetricsPublisher.java:77)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 3 more
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call$Stats com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.getStats(int) (tried Java_com_twilio_client_impl_useragent_Call_getStats and Java_com_twilio_client_impl_useragent_Call_getStats__I)
at com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.getStats(Native Method)
at com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.getStats(Call.java:207)
at com.twilio.client.impl.MetricsPublisher$1.doInBackground(MetricsPublisher.java:90)
at com.twilio.client.impl.MetricsPublisher$1.doInBackground(MetricsPublisher.java:77)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Added the gradle here :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is the Gradle dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
        compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
        compile files('libs/twilioclient-android.jar')
    }

      sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            }

                     instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')


        }
```

Comment: Add your gradle here..!!

Comment: Application level gradle please..!! which is located in your app folder and contains all dependencies..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky I have added both

Comment: Please try to replace ` compile files('libs/twilioclient-android.jar')` to `compile com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.3.9` and remove jar from lib folder..!!

Comment: Actually am using Twilio android SDK

Comment: @ Shine : Oh.. there is no gradle available for that... One thing you can do is remove `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')        compile files('libs/twilioclient-android.jar')` because this line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` automatically includes all jar in lib folder.. So keep only one of this alternatives..!! May be it will help..!!

Comment: No,I need both the jar files

Comment: I am facing the same Problem.if you get solution of it than update the answer here @Shine

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to include the native libraries as well (those in the armeabi/armeable-v7a/mips/x86 folders) and not just the jar file. They should go in the src.main.jniLibs package.

Comment: I can't believe such a stupid mistake (on my side) would have actually had an answer, thanks a bunch Brian!